# Disable moving items in GCDWebUploader

Tags: swift, gcdwebserver

I'm trying to implement GCDWebUploader in my iOS app. I want to disable 'Move Items' and 'Create Folder' options. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by editing GCDWebUploader.m Class . Go to Pods>GCDWebServer>GCDWebUploader>GCDWebUploader.m you will see following function .[image]

Edit function as your requirement. for example I don't want let user to create new folder then i need to change in following functions:

```
- (BOOL)shouldCreateDirectoryAtPath:(NSString*)path {
         return NO;
    }
```

if you face following warning just click unlock :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GCDWebUploader` class directory, create a subclass called `MyWebUploader` and override `-shouldMoveItemFromPath:toPath:` and `-shouldCreateDirectoryAtPath:` to return NO.